# replace the existing fuerte with a new copy

Tags: ros, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ubuntu 12.04 and ros fuerte

Hi,

I currently have fuerte and ubuntu 12.04. I would like to remove all the components of fuerte and again install a new copy of fuerte with all the components. I think i have messed up some files in opt/ros/fuerte.

Any suggestions?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62735/replace-the-existing-fuerte-with-a-new-copy/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you manually messed with files in /opt/ros? Generally there is no need to do so.

1. Uninstall all fuerte packages with config removal: `sudo aptitude purge --prompt ros-fuerte~n`
2. Check directories for left files you don't want anymore:

- /opt/ros
- ~/.ros
- ~/ros_workspace, ~/ros_stacks or similar
- ...?

3. [Install fuerte](http://www.ros.org/wiki/fuerte/Installation)

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-05-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-05-16**:
At the command line: `sudo apt-get remove ros-fuerte-*`, then re-install.